# keep old value input in django model form

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

In Laravel, we used old('field_name') to display previous input values. How can I do this in Django form model? I mean If the validation is unsuccessful the input value will be deleted. I want its previous value to be preserved and not need to be typed.
mean when submitting invalid form, field fields should keep the same invalid value in input value.

```
class AddMenuForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        x=super(AddMenuForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        return x
    class Meta:
        model=Menu
        fields="__all__"

        widgets = {
            'title': forms.TextInput(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control',
                'id':'inputname',
                'placeholder':  "نام آیتم"
            }),
            'url': forms.TextInput(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control',
                'id': 'inputurl',
                'placeholder': " mr-keshi.ir /"
            }),
view :

 class addMenu(FormView):
        template_name = 'Menu/addMenu.html'
        success_url = reverse_lazy('Menu')
        form_class = AddMenuForm
    
        def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
            if (self.kwargs['menu'] not in Menu.placeMenu):
                # Todo: send error message
                pass
            data = super(addMenu, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
            data['places'] = Menu.placeMenu
            data['place'] = self.kwargs['menu']
            return data
    
        def form_valid(self, form):
            print("form valid")
            menu = self.kwargs.get('menu')
            if (menu in Menu.placeMenu):
                form.save()
            else:
                pass
    
                # Todo: send error message
            # Todo:send success message
            return True
        def form_invalid(self, form):
            print("form is not valid")
            return super(addMenu, self).form_invalid(form)
```

html template

```
                                    <form method="post" action="{% url 'addMenu' menu=place%}">
                                    {% csrf_token %}
                                        <div class="form-row mb-4">
                                            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                                <label for="inputname">نام آیتم</label>
                                                {{ form.title }}
                                                {% if form.title.errors %}
                                                       <div style="color: #ef2d2d;margin-bottom: -60px !important;" class="alert alert-arrow-right alert-icon-right alert-light-danger mb-2 mt-2" role="alert">
                                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-alert-circle"><circle cx="12" cy="12" r="10"></circle><line x1="12" y1="8" x2="12" y2="12"></line><line x1="12" y1="16" x2="12" y2="16"></line></svg>
                                        <strong>هشدار!</strong>{{ form.title.errors }}
                                    </div>
                                                {% endif %}

                                           
                                    </form>
```

Comment: Use `form.field.value`, can you share your html?

Comment: yes i share my html code

Comment: Please try to format your question correctly,  html template is difficult to understand.

Comment: yes of course, i edaited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`initial`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#initial-form-values) parameter to set the initial value for a field, which will be displayed even if the form is submitted unsuccessfully so in forms:

```py
class AddMenuForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.instance:
            self.fields['title'].initial = self.instance.title

    class Meta:
        model = Menu
        fields = "__all__"

        widgets = {
            'title': forms.TextInput(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control',
                'id': 'inputname',
                'placeholder': 'نام آیتم'
            }),
            'url': forms.TextInput(attrs={
                'class': 'form-control',
                'id': 'inputurl',
                'placeholder': 'mr-keshi.ir /'
            }),
        }
```

Here, `self.instance.title` will be the current value of the `title` field.

Then with your current template, using `{{form.title}}` (which you already had it) it will display `initial` value.